# Seeking for Mobile application skills and knowledge

Tags: android

I am very beginner and want to gain enough knowledge about mobile application and be a good mobile application developer because i am very interested in this field so kindly request you where i should start my journey

I try to be a very good mobile application developer in my future where i will able to do job in my desire company.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, it depends on which platform(s) you want to develop on. for iOS, I suggest you get started with the official apple resources, including books and documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/

here is the android getting started guide:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp

additionally, you should research other languages that can be used for development such as flutter, and don't be afraid to ask questions and get help!

wishing you all the success in your coding journey!